# How to get dynamic innerHTML values?

Tags: javascript, html

So I retrieve a list of data and each piece of data has an ID provided by SQL. The ID is stored in a `<p>` tag, and I extract the ID from the `<p>` tag using `innerHTML`.

I have an event handler that will delete the element on click based on its ID, But after I click delete on my first element, the `innerHTML` value remains the same. For example, say the ID of the first element was 10, once I click delete, it will delete it. But once I click delete on the element with the ID of 11, it still says the value is 10 and will NOT delete the element with the ID of 11.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target && e.target.id === 'delete-btn') {

    // Reset the notification bar to be displayed again
    resetNotification();

    let movieToDeleteID = document.getElementById('primary-key').innerHTML;
    console.log(movieToDeleteID)

    await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/movies/delete', { movieToDeleteID })
      .then(response => {
        showNotification(response);
        movieID.value = ''
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
})
```

This is the code I'm using currently.

How can I make it so that the value of `movieToDeleteID` changes with each click of the delete button to reflect that element's ID?

Thank you!

Comment: could you please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: pls provide the html, the guy in the answers already assume the problem but the html code is needed to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line
    `let movieToDeleteID = document.getElementById('primary-key').innerHTML;`

will always get the inner HTML of the element with `id='primary-key'`-- and every `id` value on your page must be unique.
If this element's `innerHTML` content doesn't change between clicks, every click will have the same result as the first.

(The same goes for your `id='delete-btn'`, by the way: there can be only one such element on your page. And your script only runs when you click that particular element, but I think this is probably what you intended.)

If you have one `p` element per movie, each holding a different movieID, you need to make sure they don't share `id` values, which may mean you want to use a different selector (besides `.getElementById`), such as `.querySelector` or `.getElementsByClassName`.

---

It's impossible to give you a 100% solution without seeing your HTML, but **here's how it could work** in a fabricated HTML structure:

```js
// Selects the outermost div
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// Calls `deleteMovie` on click
container.addEventListener("click", deleteMovie);

// Defines `deleteMovie`
function deleteMovie(event){

  // Gets the clicked element and quits early if it's not a button
  const clickedEl = event.target;
  if(!clickedEl.classList.contains("delete-btn")){ return; }

  // Gets the text in the `primary-key` element (identifying its parent div as well)
  const
    movieDiv = clickedEl.parentElement,
    idParagraph = movieDiv.querySelector(".primary-key"),
    movieIdToDelete = idParagraph.textContent;

  // Calls the DB-communication function (which, here, just logs success)
  sendDeleteRequestToDatabase(movieIdToDelete);

  // Calls a function to update the page
  hideMovieFromList(movieIdToDelete);
}

// Defines `sendDeleteRequestToDatabase`
function sendDeleteRequestToDatabase(movieId){
  console.log(`Deleted movie #${movieId}`);
}

//Defines `hideMovieFromList`
function hideMovieFromList(movieId){

  // Selects all elements w/ `class='primary-key'`
  let idPs = document.getElementsByClassName("primary-key");

  // Loops through selected elements to find matching text
  for(let p of idPs){
    if(p.textContent === movieId){

      // Removes movie div from top-level div
      const movieDiv = p.parentElement;
      container.removeChild(movieDiv);
      break; // We already found a match, so might as well stop looking
    }
  }
}
```

```css
h3, p{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.movie{ width: 15em; border: 1px solid grey; margin: 3px; padding: 3px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="movie">
    <h3 class="title">Dracula</h3>
    <p class="genre">Horror</p>
    <p class="primary-key">1</p>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div class="movie">
    <h3 class="title">Captain Marvel</h3>
    <p class="genre">Action</p>
    <p class="primary-key">2</p>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div class="movie">
    <h3 class="title">When Harry Met Sally</h3>
    <p class="genre">Comedy</p>
    <p class="primary-key">3</p>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```